# Classic ASP paypal integration with express checkout

Tags: paypal, asp-classic

I have a fully working Classic ASP paypal integration (yay!)

I set up my variables and call the express checkout like this:

```
paymentAmount = RS_OrderHeader01("PaymentAmount")
currencyCodeType = "GBP"
paymentType = "Sale"
solutionType = "Mark"
OrderDescription = "My order description"
returnURL = "http://www.myurl.co.uk/transactioncomplete.asp"
cancelURL = "http://www.myurl.co.uk/transactioncancelled.asp"
Set resArray = CallShortcutExpressCheckout (paymentAmount, currencyCodeType, paymentType, returnURL, cancelURL)
```

That all works fine apart from the fact that there is no description being passed across. I would also like to add individual items from my basket to the final transaction in paypal.

The integration I am using is from a download from the Paypal site that hinges around this 'include' file:

```
<%
    ' ===================================================
    ' PayPal API Include file
    ' 
    ' Defines all the global variables and the wrapper functions 
    '-----------------------------------------------------------

    Dim gv_APIEndpoint
    Dim gv_APIUserName
    Dim gv_APIPassword
    Dim gv_APISignature
    Dim gv_Version
    Dim gv_BNCode
    Dim gv_ProxyServer
    Dim gv_ProxyServerPort 
    Dim gv_Proxy

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Authentication Credentials for making the call to the server
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SandboxFlag = true

    '------------------------------------
    ' PayPal API Credentials
    ' Replace <API_USERNAME> with your API Username
    ' Replace <API_PASSWORD> with your API Password
    ' Replace <API_SIGNATURE> with your Signature
    '------------------------------------

     gv_APIUserName = "myusername"
     gv_APIPassword = "1404738820"
     gv_APISignature = "AFcWxV21CRCpSSRl31AuDrEW4a9MiULwvS8UDzCPvE28G8"


    '-----------------------------------------------------
    ' The BN Code only applicable for partners
    '----------------------------------------------------

    gv_BNCode = "PP-ECWizard"

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Define the PayPal URLs.  
    '   This is the URL that the buyer is first sent to do authorize payment with their paypal account
    '   change the URL depending if you are testing on the sandbox
    '   or going to the live PayPal site
    '
    ' For the sandbox, the URL is       https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=
    ' For the live site, the URL is        https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if SandboxFlag = true Then
        gv_APIEndpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp"
        PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token="
    Else
        gv_APIEndpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp"
        PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token="
    End If 

    gv_Version  = "93"

    'WinObjHttp Request proxy settings.
    gv_ProxyServer  = "127.0.0.1"
    gv_ProxyServerPort = "808"
    gv_Proxy        = 2 'setting for proxy activation
    gv_UseProxy     = False

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
    ' Inputs:  
    '       paymentAmount: Total value of the shopping cart
    '       currencyCodeType: Currency code value the PayPal API
    '       paymentType: PaymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       returnURL: The page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
    '       cancelURL: The page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the SetExpressCheckout call Response.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

    Function CallShortcutExpressCheckout( paymentAmount, currencyCodeType, paymentType, returnURL, cancelURL) 

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        nvpstr  = "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(paymentAmount) & _
                            "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION")&"=" & Server.URLEncode(paymentType) & _
                            "&" & Server.URLEncode("RETURNURL") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(returnURL) & _
                            "&" & Server.URLEncode("CANCELURL") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(cancelURL) & _ 
                            "&" & server.UrlEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(currencyCodeType)

        SESSION("currencyCodeType") = currencyCodeType    
        SESSION("PaymentType")  = paymentType

        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        ' Make the API call to PayPal
        ' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
        ' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Set resArray = hash_call("SetExpressCheckout",nvpstr)

        ack = UCase(resArray("ACK"))
        If ack="SUCCESS" Then
            ' Save the token parameter in the Session 
            SESSION("token") = resArray("TOKEN")
        End If

        set CallShortcutExpressCheckout = resArray  

    End Function

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
    ' Inputs:  
    '       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
    '       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value the PayPal API
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
    '       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
    '       shipToName:     the Ship to name entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToStreet:       the Ship to Street entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToCity:         the Ship to City entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToState:        the Ship to State entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToCountryCode:  the Code for Ship to Country entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToZip:          the Ship to ZipCode entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToStreet2:      the Ship to Street2 entered on the merchant's site
    '       phoneNum:           the phoneNum  entered on the merchant's site
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the SetExpressCheckout call Response.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    Function CallMarkExpressCheckout(paymentAmount, currencyCodeType, paymentType, returnURL, cancelURL, shipToName, shipToStreet, shipToCity, shipToState, shipToCountryCode, shipToZip, shipToStreet2, phoneNum) 
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        nvpstr  = "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(paymentAmount) & _
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION")&"=" & Server.URLEncode(paymentType) & _
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("RETURNURL") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(returnURL) & _
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("CANCELURL") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(cancelURL) & _ 
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("ADDROVERRIDE") & "=1" & _ 
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(shipToName) & _ 
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(shipToStreet) & _ 
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(shipToStreet2) & _ 
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(shipToCity) & _ 
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(shipToState) & _ 
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(shipToCountryCode) & _ 
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(shipToZip) & _ 
                    "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(phoneNum) & _ 
                    "&"& server.UrlEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(currencyCodeType)

                SESSION("currencyCodeType") = currencyCodeType    
        SESSION("PaymentType")  = paymentType

        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        ' Make the API call to PayPal to set the Express Checkout token
        '   If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
        '   If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Set resArray = hash_call("SetExpressCheckout",nvpstr)

        ack = UCase(resArray("ACK"))
        If ack="SUCCESS" Then
            ' Save the token parameter in the Session 
            SESSION("token") = resArray("TOKEN")
        End If

        set CallMarkExpressCheckout = resArray  

    End Function

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API and makes the API call.
    '
    ' Inputs:  
    '       token:  The token value returned by the SetExpressCheckout call
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails Call Response.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    Function GetShippingDetails( token )
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' At this point, the buyer has completed authorizing the payment
        ' at PayPal.  The function will call PayPal to obtain the details
        ' of the authorization, incuding any shipping information of the
        ' buyer.  Remember, the authorization is not a completed transaction
        ' at this state - the buyer still needs an additional step to finalize
        ' the transaction
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------

            '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Build a second API request to PayPal, using the token as the
        '  ID to get the details on the payment authorization
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        nvpstr="&TOKEN=" & token

        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Make the API call and store the results in an array.  
        '   If the call was a success, show the authorization details, and provide
        '   an action to complete the payment.  
        '   If failed, show the error
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        set resArray = hash_call("GetExpressCheckoutDetails",nvpstr)
        ack = UCase(resArray("ACK"))
        If ack="SUCCESS" Then
            ' Save the token parameter in the Session 
            SESSION("PAYERID") = resArray("PAYERID")
        End If      
        set GetShippingDetails = resArray
    End Function

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API and makes the call.
    '
    ' Inputs:  
    '       finalPaymentAmount:     The final total of the shopping cart including Shipping, Handling and other fees
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the DoExpressCheckoutPayment Call Response.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    Function ConfirmPayment( finalPaymentAmount )

        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        '----   Use the values stored in the session from the previous SetEC call   
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        token           = SESSION("token")
        currCodeType    = SESSION("currencyCodeType")
        paymentType     = SESSION("PaymentType")
        payerID         = SESSION("PayerID")

        nvpstr          =   "&" & Server.URLEncode("TOKEN") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(token) & "&" &_
                            Server.URLEncode("PAYERID")&"=" &Server.URLEncode(payerID) & "&" &_
                            Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION")&"=" & Server.URLEncode(paymentType) & "&" &_
                            Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT") &"=" & Server.URLEncode(finalPaymentAmount) & "&" &_ 
                            Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE")& "=" &Server.URLEncode(currCodeType)
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
        ' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        set ConfirmPayment = hash_call("DoExpressCheckoutPayment",nvpstr)
    End Function

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the DoDirectPayment API and makes the call.
    '
    ' Inputs:  
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       paymentAmount:          Total value of the shopping cart
    '       creditCardType      Credit card type has to one of the following values: Visa or MasterCard or Discover or Amex or Switch or Solo 
    '       creditCardNumber    Credit card number
    '       expDate         Credit expiration date
    '       cvv2                CVV2
    '       firstName           Customer's First Name
    '       lastName            Customer's Last Name
    '       street          Customer's Street Address
    '       city                Customer's City
    '       state               Customer's State                
    '       zip             Customer's Zip                  
    '       countryCode     Customer's Country represented as a PayPal CountryCode
    '       currencyCode        Customer's Currency represented as a PayPal CurrencyCode
    '       
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the DoDirectPayment Call Response.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    Function DirectPayment( paymentType, paymentAmount, creditCardType, creditCardNumber, expDate, cvv2, firstName, lastName, street, city, state, zip, countryCode, currencyCode )

        ' Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation

        nvpstr  =   "&PAYMENTACTION=" & paymentType & _
                    "&AMT=" & paymentAmount &_
                    "&CREDITCARDTYPE=" & creditCardType &_
                    "&ACCT=" & creditCardNumber & _
                    "&EXPDATE=" & expDate &_
                    "&CVV2=" & cvv2 &_
                    "&FIRSTNAME=" & firstName &_
                    "&LASTNAME=" & lastName &_
                    "&STREET=" & street &_
                    "&CITY=" & city &_
                    "&STATE=" & state &_
                    "&ZIP=" & zip &_
                    "&COUNTRYCODE=" & countryCode &_
                    "&CURRENCYCODE=" & currencyCode

        nvpstr  =   URLEncode(nvpstr)       

        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
        ' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        set DirectPayment = hash_call("DoDirectPayment",nvpstr)
    End Function

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Make the API call to PayPal, using API signature.
    ' Inputs:  
    '       Method name to be called & NVP string to be sent with the post method
    ' Returns: 
    '       NVP Collection object of Call Response.
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    Function hash_call ( methodName,nvpStr )
        Set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")

        nvpStrComplete  = "METHOD=" & Server.URLEncode(methodName) & "&VERSION=" & Server.URLEncode(gv_Version) & "&USER=" & Server.URLEncode(gv_APIUserName) & "&PWD=" & Server.URLEncode(gv_APIPassword) & "&SIGNATURE=" & Server.URLEncode(gv_APISignature) & nvpStr
        nvpStrComplete  = nvpStrComplete & "&BUTTONSOURCE=" & Server.URLEncode( gv_BNCode )

        Set SESSION("nvpReqArray")= deformatNVP( nvpStrComplete )
        objHttp.open "POST", gv_APIEndpoint, False
        WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags=4
        objHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = &H3300

        If  gv_UseProxy Then
            'Proxy Call
            objHttp.SetProxy gv_Proxy,  gv_ProxyServer& ":" &gv_ProxyServerPort
        End If

        objHttp.Send nvpStrComplete

        Set nvpResponseCollection =deformatNVP(objHttp.responseText)
        Set hash_call = nvpResponseCollection
        Set objHttp = Nothing 

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
            SESSION("Message")  = ErrorFormatter(Err.Description,Err.Number,Err.Source,"hash_call")
            SESSION("nvpReqArray") =  Null
        Else
            SESSION("Message")  = Null
        End If
    End Function

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Formats the error Messages.
    ' Inputs:  
    '       
    ' Returns: 
    '       Formatted Error string
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Function ErrorFormatter ( errDesc, errNumber, errSource, errlocation )
        ErrorFormatter ="<font color=red>" & _
                                "<TABLE align = left>" &_
                                "<TR>" &"<u>Error Occured!!!</u>" & "</TR>" &_
                                "<TR>" &"<TD>Error Description :</TD>" &"<TD>"&errDesc& "</TD>"& "</TR>" &_
                                "<TR>" &"<TD>Error number :</TD>" &"<TD>"&errNumber& "</TD>"& "</TR>" &_
                                "<TR>" &"<TD>Error Source :</TD>" &"<TD>"&errSource& "</TD>"& "</TR>" &_
                                "<TR>" &"<TD>Error Location :</TD>" &"<TD>"&errlocation& "</TD>"& "</TR>" &_
                                "</TABLE>" &_
                                "</font>"
    End Function 

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Convert nvp string to Collection object.
    ' Inputs:   
    '       NVP string.
    ' Returns: 
    '       NVP Collection object created from deserializing the NVP string.
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Function deformatNVP ( nvpstr )
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim AndSplitedArray,EqualtoSplitedArray,Index1,Index2,NextIndex

        Set NvpCollection = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        AndSplitedArray = Split(nvpstr, "&", -1, 1)
        NextIndex=0

        For Index1 = 0 To UBound(AndSplitedArray)
            EqualtoSplitedArray=Split(AndSplitedArray(Index1), "=", -1, 1)
            For Index2 = 0 To UBound(EqualtoSplitedArray)
                NextIndex=Index2+1
                NvpCollection.Add URLDecode(EqualtoSplitedArray(Index2)),URLDecode(EqualtoSplitedArray(NextIndex))
                Index2=Index2+1
            Next
        Next
        Set deformatNVP = NvpCollection
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
            SESSION("Message")  = ErrorFormatter(Err.Description,Err.Number,Err.Source,"deformatNVP")
        else
            SESSION("Message")  = Null
        End If
    End Function

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose: URL Encodes a string
    ' Inputs:  
    '       String to be url encoded.
    ' Returns: 
    '       Url Encoded string.
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Function URLEncode(str) 
        On Error Resume Next

            Dim AndSplitedArray,EqualtoSplitedArray,Index1,Index2,UrlEncodeString,NvpUrlEncodeString

        AndSplitedArray = Split(nvpstr, "&", -1, 1)
        UrlEncodeString=""
        NvpUrlEncodeString=""

        For Index1 = 0 To UBound(AndSplitedArray)
            EqualtoSplitedArray=Split(AndSplitedArray(Index1), "=", -1, 1)
            For Index2 = 0 To UBound(EqualtoSplitedArray)
            If Index2 = 0 then
                UrlEncodeString=UrlEncodeString & Server.URLEncode(EqualtoSplitedArray(Index2))
            Else            
                UrlEncodeString=UrlEncodeString &"="& Server.URLEncode(EqualtoSplitedArray(Index2))
            End if
            Next
            If Index1 = 0 then
                NvpUrlEncodeString= NvpUrlEncodeString & UrlEncodeString
            Else            
                NvpUrlEncodeString= NvpUrlEncodeString &"&"&UrlEncodeString
            End if
            UrlEncodeString=""
        Next
        URLEncode = NvpUrlEncodeString

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
            SESSION("Message")  = ErrorFormatter(Err.Description,Err.Number,Err.Source,"URLEncode")
        else
            SESSION("Message")  = Null
        End If

     End Function 

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose: Decodes a URL Encoded string
    ' Inputs:  
    '       A URL encoded string
    ' Returns: 
    '       Decoded string.
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Function URLDecode(str) 
        On Error Resume Next

        str = Replace(str, "+", " ") 
        For i = 1 To Len(str) 
            sT = Mid(str, i, 1) 
            If sT = "%" Then 
                If i+2 < Len(str) Then 
                    sR = sR & _ 
                        Chr(CLng("&H" & Mid(str, i+1, 2))) 
                    i = i+2 
                End If 
            Else 
                sR = sR & sT 
            End If 
        Next 

        URLDecode = sR 
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
            SESSION("Message")  = ErrorFormatter(Err.Description,Err.Number,Err.Source,"URLDecode")
        else
            SESSION("Message")  = Null
        End If

    End Function

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  It's Workaround Method for Response.Redirect
    '           It will redirect the page to the specified url without urlencoding
    ' Inputs: 
    '       Url to redirect the page
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Function ReDirectURL( token )
        On Error Resume Next

        payPalURL = PAYPAL_URL & token & "&useraction=commit"
        response.clear
        response.status="302 Object moved"
        response.AddHeader "location", payPalURL
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
            SESSION("Message")  = ErrorFormatter(Err.Description,Err.Number,Err.Source,"ReDirectURL")
        else
            SESSION("Message")  = Null
        End If
    End Function

%>
```

As I have a fully working implementation I am reluctant to embrace a different solution (and go through a whole load more development).

I have a sneaking suspicion that the 'CallShortcutExpressCheckout' is nothing more that a glorified call to SetExpressCheckout with some very specific parameters set and that it need modification or replacing with a direct call to SetExressCheckout?

Has anyone got some sample classic ASP code?
c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add to the nvpstr more fields.
You can add also a field like "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0" to indentify your product/service id/code the user still paying for. (just a suggestion)

I've rebuild one function, but need to be tested if is working right.
Anyway this is an idea:

```
    Function CallShortcutExpressCheckout( title, description, paymentAmount, currencyCodeType, paymentType, returnURL, cancelURL) 

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    nvpstr  =           "&" & Server.URLEncode("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(title) & _
                        "&" & Server.URLEncode("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(description) & _
                        "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(paymentAmount) & _
                        "&" & Server.URLEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION")&"=" & Server.URLEncode(paymentType) & _
                        "&" & Server.URLEncode("RETURNURL") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(returnURL) & _
                        "&" & Server.URLEncode("CANCELURL") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(cancelURL) & _ 
                        "&" & server.UrlEncode("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE") & "=" & Server.URLEncode(currencyCodeType)

    SESSION("currencyCodeType") = currencyCodeType    
    SESSION("PaymentType")  = paymentType

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    ' Make the API call to PayPal
    ' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
    ' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set resArray = hash_call("SetExpressCheckout",nvpstr)

    ack = UCase(resArray("ACK"))
    If ack="SUCCESS" Then
        ' Save the token parameter in the Session 
        SESSION("token") = resArray("TOKEN")
    End If

    set CallShortcutExpressCheckout = resArray  

End Function
```